# How can I run an autorun file as root with no gui

Tags: server, sudo, gui, gksudo, autorun

I set up a server using ubuntu with no gui. I need root for some tasks that I want to autorun on this server. Normally I would just use gksudo because autorun programs never seem to work with su or sudo. gksudo will not run because there is no gui on this server. I decided to install xubuntu-desktop on it but this slows it significantly. What is a way that i can run an autorun file as root without any need for a gui?

By autorun I mean I want to create a sh script that will startup on login. I want it to have root privelages and sh scripts dont work with sudo because they run all the code as the sudo password.

Comment: what do you mean by autorun?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions based on the definition of 'autorun':

1. Windows 'autorun.ini' files places in media root directories such as CDs or USB sticks. DO NOT RUN AS ROOT, EVER.
2. Programs run when a user logs in: [Running a script after the gui has loaded](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120645/running-a-script-after-the-gui-has-loaded)
3. Programs run when the computer starts: [How to run a script during boot as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290099/how-to-run-a-script-in-boot-as-root)