# How to run a script during boot as root

Tags: boot, scripts

I had a script that automatically enables my wifi without using networkmanager, but I don't know how to run the script as root while the system is booting. How do I make the script run automatically during boot?

Comment: Auto-start programs are configured in `autostart` manifests or in `*.service` files in several locations, as well as in `init.d` or `crontab`. See this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/525845/43233

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Place the script you want to run in the /etc/init.d directory and make the script executable.

```
chmod 755 myscript
```

Once that is done create a symbolic link in the run level directory you would like to use, for example if you wanted to run a program in the graphical runlevel 2, the default runlevel for Ubuntu, you would place it in the `/etc/rc2.d` directory. You just cannot place it the directory, you must signify when it will run by indicating the startup with an “S” and the execution order is important. Place it after everything else that is in the directory by giving it a higher number.

If the last script to be run is `rc.local` and it is named `S99rc.local` then you need to add your script as `S99myscript`.

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/myscript /etc/rc3.d/S99myscript
```

Each backward compatible `/etc/rc*.d` directory has symbolic links to the `/etc/init.d/` directory.

Comment: Note that under Ubuntu Server 14.04, I needed to use `/etc/rc2.d`, instead of `rc3.d` as indicated in the example.  It seems `rc2.d` isn't just the graphical run level.

Comment: `cd /etc/rc\`cat /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf | grep "env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL" | grep -oP "\d"\`.d` will take you to which `/etc/rc?.d`directory corresponds to your default runlevel.

Comment: Instead: " If the last script to be run is `rc.local` and it is named `S99rc.local` then you need to add your script as `S99myscript`. ". Did you mean: " If the last script to be run is `myscript` and it is named `S99myscript` then you need to add your script as `S99myscript`. " ???

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't work with systemd (i.e., starting with Ubuntu 16.04). See [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47715/194670) instead.

Comment: There is no `S*rc.local` file exist

Answer (score 40):

Use a `crontab` option to make your script run after reboot,

You can do this by adding your command prefixed with the `@reboot` [nonstandard predefined scheduling definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Nonstandard_predefined_scheduling_definitions) in [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Open crontab as the root user (you *must* use `sudo` here in order to edit your *root's* crontab instead of your *user's* crontab):

```bash
sudo crontab -e
```

Then, add a record to the bottom, containing your desired command to be run as root:

```
@reboot path/to/your/executable/to/be/run/as/root
```

That will do what you want.

Note that you can see your user's and root's crontab entries as follows:

```bash
crontab -l       # list your user crontab entries
sudo crontab -l  # list root's crontab entries
```

For your command to run as root, it *must* be in your root's crontab.

Comment: Did you mean using command `crontab -e`, which does not need superuser privileges? I wonder, if it can run scripts that need to be run as root.

Comment: I tested this. It does not run the script as root.

Comment: You have to add the line while running command `sudo crontab -e` to make it run the script as root during startup.

Comment: don't forget to remove `/var/run/crond.reboot`, if not, won't execute the task

Comment: Only for the record, I'm sure that @jarno will know it already. Each user has his own cron task, so if you add it to your user's one (running crontab -e without sudo) the script will be runned by your user. So you need to run it as root to let it be able to run scripts as root on boot.

Comment: no need to remove `/var/run/crond.reboot` anymore, this sees to be fixed long ago

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 20, no need to remove /var/run/crond.reboot, could run `sudo -i -u myuser bash -c '...'`, and is much simpler than creating a systemd script.

Answer (score 30):

Include the command in `/etc/rc.local`. It will be run whenever the user's runlevel changes.

Note: You have to put the command before the last line in /etc/rc.local that contains: "exit 0".

Comment: Note: you have to put the command before the last line in `/etc/rc.local` that contains:

`exit 0`

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` in ubuntu 15.10 has in comment that "This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel." So the script could be run several times during boot, right?

Comment: @jamo, yes, on each runlevel. I don't knwo how this is related to run "at boot", which usually mean "run once at boot".

Comment: I do not have this file on debian buster

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 17.04:

1. create a script file like `disable_cdrom` in convenient for you
   location. In my case `home/yterle/disable_cdrom`. In my case:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   eject /dev/sr0 -i 1
   ```
2. make it executable `chmod 775 disable_cdrom`
3. navigate to `/etc/systemd/system` and create there a `service` file.
   For example `sudo gedit /etc/systemd/system/disable_cdrom.service`

My `disable_cdrom.service` looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Disable cdrom

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh /home/yterle/disable_cdrom

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Where `ExecStart` points to run your script with `/bin/sh`

Then run `systemctl enable disable_cdrom.service` to enable the systemd service

Comment: Voting this up as it's what I was looking for, but I think you mean `systemctl enable disable_cdrom.service`

Answer (score 5):

Include your Script file to `/etc/init.d/`
with Executable permission
then set different run level

```
$ update-rc.d script-name default
```

It will put your script on boot startup.

Comment: Does not work for me on Kali Linux v2.0. Did you mean `update-rc.d script-name enable`?

Comment: update-rc.d <script-name> default     shell script which you have copy at /etc/init.d/<script-name>

Comment: Not working for me on Ubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 4):

Create a text file like this in `/etc/cron.d/`:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

@reboot   root    yourScriptPath
```

(You should replace `yourScriptPath` with the path to the script you want to run.)

Answer (score 3):

Careful with adding the script to `rc.local` - I was stuck in splash screen because of it. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> revealed what was going on behind the splash screen (the script in `rc.local` was running).

I could not get out of it.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> or
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd>

nothing works.

I had to boot from a USB Ubuntu image, find `rc.local`, give myself permissions to file and delete it. I guess you shouldn't do stuff if you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a service under systemd. That way your script will run as sudo automatically.

Assuming you have a script `/path/to/script/my_amazing_script.sh` that you want to run at ever boot as root:

Make sure only root can work with this:

> chmod 0700 /path/to/script/my_amazing_script.sh

Then create the service file and start editing it:

> sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/run_amazing_script.service

Put this in the file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run the best script ever

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/script/my_amazing_script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Check the service runs fine by running it one time:

> sudo systemctl start run_amazing_script.service

Check the log:

> sudo journalctl -u run_amazing_script.service

If you are happy with the run, enable it to make it run upon every boot:

> sudo systemctl enable run_amazing_script.service

And if you want to stop it from running at every boot you can disable it:

> sudo systemctl disable run_amazing_script.service

Note: this solution is very similar to what YTerle posted. But since I don't have enough rep I couldn't comment nor upvote his answer