# Printing on Yocto MiniDisplay on System Startup

Tags: 12.04, display, autostart, c, yocto

I have developed a C application and I am also using a Yocto_MiniDisplay, which prints some messages from the application.

I need to start the application on System Start up, so that on the display it shows "Welcome".

I am unable to start the application automatically on system startup.
*I am also using a virtualhub application for yoctopuce devices.*

Please Help me its really urgent.

i am using ubuntu 12.04. i dont want any other applications just i need to run only my application on startup .The problem i am facing is the lcd devices are not getting initailized. currently i  have connected display with usb.

how to add time out in starting an application in ubuntu. which is the best way to add our application to system start up

Comment: Please, if it is urgent, give us more information about the problem. What is the exact problem? Why doesn't it start on startup?

Comment: lcd is not initializing

Comment: So, have you tried adding a small interval at the beginning? I mean, notice how long it takes for the LCD devices to initialize, then add a corresponding timeout. After this timeout launch your program.

Comment: hakermania: how to add time out in starting an application in ubuntu. which is the best way to add our application to system start up?

Comment: You open the "Startup Applications" program and at the `Command` field you place: `bash -c 'sleep 10 && yourprogram'` . This will wait for 10 seconds and then it will execute yourpogram.

Comment: i have tried that also . but the problem i am facing is , the device ie, Yocto -display (which is connected through usb port) is not initializing. how we could initiate an usb device at the start up.

Comment: hakermania: how to run aany application in autosartup as root user. My application runs aonly if we execute as root.. how to do that

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/290099/how-to-run-a-script-in-boot-as-root