# startup script ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, scripts, startup

Each time I startup the sistem I need to run this command `sudo xhost +`
and the `sudo service myservice restart`

I have decided to add a script to startup to avoid having to type it each time myself.

I followed the instructions from here 
[How to run a script during boot as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290099/how-to-run-a-script-during-boot-as-root)

I created myscript.sh in /etc/init.d and then ran chmod 755 on it
then I created a simlink in /etc/rc2.d/S99myscript.sh

here is the content of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo xhost +
sudo service siemcy restart
```

`ls -l /etc/init.d/my_custom_startup_script.sh`

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 54 Apr  9 10:10 /etc/init.d/my_custom_startup_script.sh`

But when I reboot seems the sript is not run, service siemcy is not running because it needs xhost + so basiclly the screept is not run. Or the script is not run at the right time. Any advice? did I put the script in the wrong place?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe service siemcy is not yet started, so you should first start it, and then restart it.

Alternatively, you could copy your code in /etc/rc.local before the exit 0 tag.

Hope it helps!