# Why does Chrome use apt-get to manage updates?

Tags: apt, google-chrome

I come from a Windows world where Chrome automagically updates itself without any intervention (other than the occasional browser restart, since I leave my browser open all the time.)

In Ubuntu, I frequently notice Chrome listed in Update Manager. I don't recall if I installed Chrome through `apt-get` or not.

Why does Chrome rely on apt-get for updates? Is there a way to have a "Windows-like" experience where it updates itself without my intervention? **This is my goal.**

Comment: Why not just run the apt update-upgrade cycle in the background?

Comment: If you have a specific goal or reason for asking this, please include that to better enable us to address your actual end-goals.

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm sure it's Chrome, the package name is `google-chrome-stable`. > installed it via the PPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome adds it's own repository on install. On https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/ it states:

> **Note:** Installing Google Chrome will **add the Google repository** so your
> system will automatically keep Google Chrome up to date. If you don’t
> want Google's repository, do “sudo touch /etc/default/google-chrome”
> before installing the package.

So unless you do that before you install it should add a repository that will keep Chrome up to date with the system upgrades.

Picture of my sources after deb install:

[image]

So yes you will get updated versions of Chrome when doing updates. (either through Software Updater or apt-get update and apt-get upgrade)

So no intervention required if just do your updates like normal, I suggest letting it do them daily, as the update process is less intensive with only a handful at a time, and there are no *forced* restarts, and the old version of a program can stay in memory while it is currently being updated - so it is be perfectly fine to have programs open while they are being updated.

Comment: I didn't realize that it even tells you that it uses apt-get for updates. Thanks for cleaing that up.

Answer (score 0):

As parto said, you can just make it update in the background. To do that here are two options:

1. Make a startup script that runs as root (see here: [How to run a script during boot as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290099/how-to-run-a-script-during-boot-as-root)) with the contents

`apt-get upgdate && apt-get upgrade chromium -y`

You may need to change the name of chrome to whatever the package name actually is.

2. You can do the same thing with a cron job, and run it as root (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015485/is-it-possible-to-make-a-bash-file-run-as-root-in-crontab) with the same contents

Also, Rinzwind has a good point in the comments - you're likely using chromium as Google Chrome doesn't use apt

Comment: chrome does use apt. It adds a ppa for it during the install process

Comment: @MGodby, I don't think that's true - I just installed it and there are no new PPAs on my system

Comment: Oh, yes, you are correct that it does not add a ppa during install. The ppa is optional.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a way to get the "windows-like" experience of having Google Chrome "update itself."

apt-get is the cleanest and most well-integrated (from OS perspective) of managing updates for your system.

apt-get also affords the system admin a good "one stop shop" for controlling versioning and updates. For these reasons, Google made the design choice to have automatic updates be ran by apt-get for the simplicity and convenience of the user.