# How to make VBoxClient load with the --clipboard option when launched?

Tags: virtualbox

I use VirtualBox for using Ubuntu 15.04, and I run at guest

```
$ sudo VBoxClient --clipboard
```

every time I want to copy something from host to guest. Every time I mean once per bootup.

**How I can make the command run with sudo at guest boot time?**

I have already set `Shared Clipboard` to `Bidirectional` value at VirtualBox Settings.

Comment: When you say "boot time" do you mean host boot or guest boot?

Comment: i mean guest boot

Comment: @GeoMint Maybe not what you are looking for but why don't you turn on the "share clipboard option" in your virtualBox parameters?

Comment: I have already set share clipboard option to Bidirectional

Comment: You run that command on the host in order to launch the VBox client and boot your VM, right? Why not just make `VBoxClient` an alias to `sudo VBoxClient --clipboard`?

Comment: My host operating system is windows 8.1

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/290107/411540) could help.

Comment: can you tell me how to do this? i am not into the symlinks.

Comment: All the command are in the answer from the link: Once the script is in `/etc/init.d` with the correct permissions `chmod 755 Myscript`. You go to the directory of the correct runlevel: e.g. `/etc/rc2.d` Then you do a `ls` find the last script in this level (highest number after S). And then you create the symlink using `ln -s /etc/init.d/Myscript /etc/rc2.d/SHighestNumberMyscript`. Just let me know if something does not work or is not clear.

Comment: @Prolix that doesn't work. The command needs to be run after the GUI has been loaded since it applies to the X clipboard. It is best to run this after login and not at boot.

Comment: @terdon Good catch! I got mislead by the "guest boot time" part of the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be to give your user the right to run the command without entering a password and then adding it to the list of startup programs. First, run `sudo visudo` and add this line to the file (change `geomint` to your actual user name):

```
geomint ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/VBoxClient --clipboard
```

Then, use the tools provided by your desktop environment to add the command to your startup applications. Instructions for Unity can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/48327/85695).

Alternatively, do it manually. Create a file called `~/.config/autostart/VboxClipbvoard.desktop` with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=sudo VBoxClient --clipboard
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=VBox clipboard
Name=VBox clipboard
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=
```

Now reboot, and it should work as expected.