# Need Help Getting Script to Run At Boot (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Headless)

Tags: 14.04, boot, scripts

I've searched everywhere and done my homework before posting, but still can't get one thing to work.  I have an Ubunutu 14.04 server (headless) and am trying to figure out what I'd think would be a simple task, but cannot get it to work and it's driving me insane.  Below are the details...

**What I'm Trying to Do**

At boot, I want 3 applications to automatically start.  The 3 strings are already in a bash script located in /etc/init.d which when run manually executes properly.  No matter what I've tried, I cannot get it to run at boot, though.  My session lists that I'm at runlevel 2.

*Note:  The server is remote and I access via SSH.  Due to not being local, I obviously cannot immediately see the echo during initial boot stages.  I also do not use GRUB with this server.*

**What I've Tried**

*None have worked :(*

- Editing rc.local (using nano) in /etc and /etc/init.d and adding the commands or script
- Verified that rc.local was enabled for my runlevel (plus enabled it for all runlevels to test)
- Creating symlinks to the script which had "S99" appended to the beginning of the name in /etc/init.d in /etc/rc1.d, /etc/rc2.d... all the way to rc6.d [as described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290099/how-to-run-a-script-during-boot-as-root)
- Adding to Startup in Unity - Yes, it's headless, but one of the things I'm trying to start is for the VNC Server.  As predicted, apps configured here require Unity to auto launch which it doesn't
- A few other things I can't remember right now

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated - Thanks!