# Script won't Start on Logon of Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: networking, bash, scripts, network-manager

I am wrote a Bash script that will be run on log-on for the Raspberry Pi running Kali Linux.

The issue lies when the linux system starts up, I have to physically SSH into the terminal for the script to run! Why?

I put the script inside, .bash_profile, which is a known file to be called at start-up.

I also made sure to allow for automatic root log-on, after boot.

Answer (score 1):

`.bash_profile` is executed when you login via tty or terminal emulator (or ssh), you should put your script into `.profile` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Do I put it at the end of the file?

Comment: exactly, put it at the end of file

Comment: @AndroidDev I know, currently testing his idea and if it works I'll mark it as thus.

Comment: Okay,  I put the script call at the end of the .profile file, and rebooted the system. It had no effect.

Comment: That's kind of strange. Only a blind call - have you marked your script as executable?

Comment: yeah,  I used chmod +x bootloader.sh and then inside the .profile, I put ./bootloader.sh at the very end of the .profile file.

Comment: Please try to put absolute address of file, like /home/xxx/<nameofthescript>.sh

Comment: the absolute would be .~/bootloader.sh if its in root right?

Comment: OK, I did a little research, try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/290099/how-to-run-a-script-during-boot-as-root

Comment: Okay I'll try those later.