# usb_modeswitch.conf isn't loaded on startup

Tags: 16.04, usb-modem, huawei, usb-modeswitch

I'm trying to configure the PC to connect to the Internet over Huawei modem when it's started. However, after start, the modem is recognized as Mass storage device. I can switch it to correct mode by running

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 14fe -J
```

I need the modem to work from start, so I figured out that I need to add the following to /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf:

```
DefaultVendor=0x12d1
DefaultProduct=0x14fe

TargetVendor=0x12d1
TargetProduct=0x1506
HuaweiNewMode=1
```

This works when I load the configuration file by running `sudo usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf`, but not when computer starts. Anybody knows how to apply the configuration on startup?

UPDATE: I tried also adding the following line to /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules:

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="14fe", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

or

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="14fe", RUN+="usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 14fe -J"
```

I still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by running the usb_modeswitch command from a startup script, as described in [How to run a script during boot as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290099/how-to-run-a-script-during-boot-as-root) (highest rated answer).
One of the commenters states that this won't work on Ubuntu 16.04 or later, but in my case it does.

I know that this solution may seem "dirty" to some, but I already spent too much time trying to do it the "proper" way.

Answer (score 0):

I think that after update udev rule You have to update initramfs

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

my file with udev rule is

cat /etc/udev/rules.d/41-huawei_e3372.rules

```
# Huawei E3372
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="14fe", RUN+="/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 14fe -V 12d1 -P 1506 -J"
```

after that you can verify whether the file has been uploaded to the initramfs image
by command

```
lsinitramfs /boot/initrd.img|grep 41-huawei_e3372.rules
```