# Script run with .desktop has different results than run from terminal

Tags: bash, .desktop

I am trying to launch a script after a user has loged into the computer using the GUI. This script requires user input through the terminal. I have tried the following

.desktop file in ~/.config/autostart --> Does not work

When using this the output is not the same as that of the script running in the terminal. It closes the opened applications and vpn breaks the network connection. Neither of these occurr using the normal terminal.

My desktop enviroment is xubuntu version 20.04.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "........ Start Up Script ........."
echo "sudo priveledges necessary for VPN" 

#Connect VPN to Server in Czech Republic
sudo protonvpn c --cc CZ

#Prompt To Mount Encrypted Files
read -p 'Mount Encrypted Files? [ y/n ] ' encryptedmount
case $encryptedmount in
    [Yy]* ) veracrypt -t -k "" --pim=0 --protect-hidden=no /media/peterthegreat/Main_Data/Files /media/veracrypt1; break;;
    [Nn]* ) ;;
esac

# Prompt To Update Packages
read -p 'Upgrade and Update System? [ y/n ] ' upgradeandupdate
case $upgradeandupdate in
    [Yy]* ) apt-get update && apt-get upgrade; break;;
    [Nn]* ) ;;
esac

#Prompt to Open Tilix
read -p 'Open Tilix? [ y/n ] ' til
case $til in
    [Yy]* ) cd /home/peterthegreat; tilix --session=~/Documents/Start_Up/TilixSetup.json -e &;;
    [Nn]* ) ;;
esac
disown %1

#Prompt to Open Firefox
read -p 'Open Firefox? [ y/n ] ' firefox
case $firefox in
    [Yy]* ) firefox &;;
    [Nn]* ) ;;
esac
disown %1

echo "....... Done ......."
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, the command should be a full path and *regex* in bash, abbreviations may not work.

Comment: I don understand the second part of yout comment about regex and abreviations. Could you rephrase?

Comment: `sudo` is supposed to be executed as root. You can imitate on the running terminal. I think a better explanation here https://askubuntu.com/questions/889632/startup-script-with-sudo-in-ubuntu-16-10

Comment: I tried the suggestion of the command line in the question you link but it only opened the terminal for 10 seconds and did not run the rest of the commands. This .desktop does run but it does so differently than if the script were run from the terminal `[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=0.9.4
Type=Application
Name=Start Up
Comment=Set Up of Workspace
Exec=/home/peterthegreat/Bash\\ Scripts/StartUp.sh
OnlyShowIn=XFCE;
RunHook=0
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=true
Hidden=false
`

Comment: Well, to make it simple, why don't you put this `StartUp.sh` into `.bashrc` or something automatically loads and executes all inside a file when you get to login a desktop?

Comment: I have added it to my path temporally but hoped to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [.desktop file spec](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/) -- its not expecting a bash script.

Your .desktop file needs to look something like

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=<path to your bash script>
Terminal=True
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
NoDisplay=false
Hidden=false
Name[en_GB]=VPN
Comment[en_GB]=Creates a VPN
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=9
```

where "path to your bash script" points to the script that you show in the question (probably best saved in /usr/local/bin)

Comment: I have tried your fix my desktop file is now `[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/local/bin/StartUp.sh
Terminal=true
NoDisplay=false
Hidden=false
Name[en_GB]=startup
Comment[en_GB]=Run frequent start up commands` but still has the same issues. I have not incluede the lines with GNOME since my environment is XFCE.

Comment: `Gdk-Message: 21:20:51.996: tilix: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.0.` is the error return when using nohup on nohup.out