# Make fn key run brightness script on Macbook pro 11, 5

Tags: lubuntu, brightness, macbook, macbook-pro

Laptop: MacbookPro 11,5 with AMD gpu

OS: Lubuntu 17.04

I followed the instruction at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBookPro11,x and it worked.

1. disable automatic gpu switching in MacOS X (not sure if that helped).
2. download and compile https://github.com/problame/gmux_backlight
3. `sudo setpci -v -H1 -s 00:01.00 BRIDGE_CONTROL=0`
4. `sudo gmux_backlight 120`
5. can adjust brightness with script.

The problem is that

1. Have to use `sudo` everytime
2. The F1/F2 key do not change brightness.

How to fix this?

---

Update (following [terdon](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon)'s answer)

Moved the compiled `gmux_backlight` to `/usr/sbin/`

Used `sudo visudo` to let each of the user run `gmux_backlight` with `sudo` and without entering password.

```
<username1> ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/gmux_backlight
<username2> ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/gmux_backlight
<username3> ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/gmux_backlight
```

Create `/etc/init.d/gmux_backlight_fix` and `sudo chmod +x` the script.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
setpci -v -H1 -s 00:01.00 BRIDGE_CONTROL=0 >/dev/null
```

Symlink the script to run level 2 (the grpahical run level for Ubuntu) with lowest priority (99) by following [How to run a script during boot as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290099/how-to-run-a-script-during-boot-as-root).

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/gmux_backlight_fix /etc/rc2.d/S99gmux_backlight_fix
```

Added to  section of `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` for each user.

```xml
<keyboard>
  <chainQuitKey>C-g</chainQuitKey>

  <!-- My Keys -->
  <keybind key="XF86LaunchA">
    <action name="Execute">
      <command>sudo gmux_backlight -10</command>
    </action>
  </keybind>
  <keybind key="XF86LaunchB">
    <action name="Execute">
      <command>sudo gmux_backlight +10</command>
    </action>
  </keybind>
```

I use Fn-F3 and Fn-F4 because Lubuntu can not automatically detect Fn-F1 and Fn-F2 on the laptop.

Initially I wrote a bash script that takes argument and grant every user to run it with sudo. A while later, I worry that people can break the bash script and run any command with sudo privilege. So I use the compiled binary instead of my bash script.

The old bash script is `/usr/sbin/gmux_capped_backlight`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -e

# setpci
setpci -v -H1 -s 00:01.00 BRIDGE_CONTROL=0 >/dev/null

# Get current brightness
CB="$( cat /sys/class/backlight/gmux_backlight/brightness )"

# Split characters of argument
arg=$1
first_char=${arg:0:1}
other_char=${arg:1}

# Desired Brightness
if [ $first_char == "+" ]; then 
    Brightness=$(expr $CB + $other_char)
elif [ $first_char == "-" ]; then
    Brightness=$(expr $CB - $other_char)
else
    Brightness=$arg
fi

# Limit the range of brightness #
Max=1024
Min=0

if [ $Brightness -gt $Max ]; then
    Brightness=$Max
fi
if [ $Brightness -lt $Min ]; then
    Brightness=$Min
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you can already adjust this using a script, it looks like you're almost there already. You just need to:

1. Set up `sudo` to allow executing that particular script by your user without a password. First, open a terminal and run `sudo visudo`. That will bring up a window of your default editor. Add this line to the file:

   ```
   terdon  ALL=NOPASSWD:/path/to/your/script
   ```

   Obviously, change `terdon` to your user name and change `/path/to/your/script` to whatever the path to your script is. It will make your life easier if you can make sure that path has no spaces. Now, save the file and close it.
2. You can now run the script without needing to enter root's password, so all you need to do is assign the commands to raise and lower brightness to the F1/F2 keys. I don't use LXDE, but I found a forum thread [here](https://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?t=31229) which suggests you can do it by editing `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` and adding something like this:

   ```
   <keybind key="F2">
     <action name="Execute">
       <command>/path/to/your/script increaseBrightness</command>
     </action>
   </keybind>
   <keybind key="F1">
     <action name="Execute">
       <command>/path/to/your/script decreaseBrightness</command>
     </action>
   </keybind>
   ```

   For both cases, use whatever parameter your script would take to raise/lower the brightness.

   Alternatively, you can also do this by installing `xbindkeys`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
   ```

   Create the default settings file:

   ```
   xbindkeys --defaults > `~/.xbindkeysrc`
   ```

   Get the right keycodes for your keys. It will likely be something like `F1`. Then, edit `~/.xbindkeysrc` and add these:

   ```
   "/path/to/your/script increaseBrightness"
   F2

   "/path/to/your/script decreaseBrightness"
   F1
   ```

   Finally, run `xbindkeys` and your shortcuts should work. Add it to your list of startup programs so it is always run when you log in.

Comment: +1 for great informative answer that is also well-written. Minor point is on all laptop keyboards I've seen it would be `Fn`+`F1` and `Fn`+`F2` insted of `F1`/`F2` because your F1 and F2 keys would never reach normal apps. Obviously, this would be OP oversight and not yours. But I'm curious if `xbindkeys` can trap `Fn`+`Fx` as I've never tried it and it might make a great user-friendly GUI project down the road to link key combos to scripts.

Comment: @win macs use the F keys with no modifier for this sort of thing, so the OP meant what they wrote, I think. But that's why I mentioned they should get the right code using `xbindkeys -k`, to be sure. And yes, it can bind them. On my keyboard, for example, which has a function key, that's recognized.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I haven't used Mac since 1984 and they've changed a lot since then. Nice to know `xbindkeys` recognizes `Fn` key combos. I'm just so used to other OS's not being able to recognize that in the past.

Comment: Is it a good idea to let all users run that script with sudo?

Comment: @rxu that only allows your user to run the script with sudo. That's why you need to put your user name where I put `terdon`. And yes, it is a risk. To make it slightly less risky, put the script in a directory  other users don't have write access to, like `/usr/local/bin`. The real danger here is someone maliciously changing the script to something destructive (consider `rm -rf /usr /etc /lib` for example). Since you run it with `sudo`, anything dangerous put in there will be run with elevated privileges. Saving it in `/usr/bin` makes that harder to do.