# Host name reverts to old name after reboot in 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04

This may be related to running 18.04 LTS as a virtual machine (Host is Win 2016 DC) but I can't figure it out how.  I have tried every method of I know of to change the hostname but it always reverts to the hostname I entered when I built the machine on reboot.  I have tried the following:

1. hostnamectl set-hostname xxx.
2. Editing hostname directly.
3. Adding --static to hostnamectl.
4. Editing hosts file and adding desired hostname.
5. Searching drive for references to old hostname before reboot.
6. A few other weird suggestions I found on the internet not worth mentioning.

I have no DNS for this server at this time.

Example:

```
XXXX@iwrxmail:~# hostnamectl
Static hostname: iwrxmail
Pretty hostname: Interwrx Ubuntu Mail Server
Transient hostname: ctl
     Icon name: computer-vm
       Chassis: vm
    Machine ID: 01ef0d836d2c4945b51a4fab8e506381
       Boot ID: e6608fe238d843f883cde52af7631a79
Virtualization: microsoft
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
        Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-20-generic
  Architecture: x86-64
XXXX@iwrxmail:~# hostnamectl set-hostname test
XXXX@iwrxmail:~# hostnamectl
Static hostname: test
     Icon name: computer-vm
       Chassis: vm
    Machine ID: 01ef0d836d2c4945b51a4fab8e506381
       Boot ID: e6608fe238d843f883cde52af7631a79
Virtualization: microsoft
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
        Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-20-generic
  Architecture: x86-64
root@iwrxmail:~# cat /etc/hostname
test
root@iwrxmail:~# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts 

However on reboot I get this again ....

XXXX@iwrxmail:~# hostnamectl
Static hostname: iwrxmail
     Icon name: computer-vm
       Chassis: vm
    Machine ID: 01ef0d836d2c4945b51a4fab8e506381
       Boot ID: 25a00676b22048eb8d43492c9de4f147
Virtualization: microsoft
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
        Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-20-generic
Architecture: x86-64
```

I had had this issue with the beta of 18.04, but I figured I would wait for the release copy.  I also considered it might be a problem with the fact I had cloned the VMs, but this was a brand new version built from scratch with the just released distro.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sharing-displayname.html

Answer (score 83):

First edit /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg and set the parameter "preserve_hostname" from "false" to "true" and then edit /etc/hostname.

Comment: Works like a charm.  I would have never gotten that from the comment line above it: " # This will cause the set+update hostname module to not operate (if true) ".    Thanks so much, so many incorrect methods out on the web.

Comment: This file does not exists in my os. Not even /etc/cloud folder

Comment: I think it would be more correct to edit where the old hostname is explicitly left (see Levi H's proposal further down), namely in '/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net/user-data', than to simply disable reading that file by editing '/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg'.

Comment: @longman Except I here (a Debian in a vserver) don't see your path, but I do see /etc/cloud.

Comment: it works in `Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS`

Comment: This ruined my afternoon - I wanted to change hostnames with a setup script and this dumb cloud-init thing kept reverting the - thanks

Answer (score 28):

The hostname is being reset by `cloud-init` which can either be disabled as follows (after which you can set the hostname in the normal way e.g. using `hostnamectl`):

```
sudo touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled
```

Or you can use cloud-init and create/modify the `user-data` file (usually found at: `/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net/user-data`) so that the `hostname:` entry is set to the desired hostname (provided `preserve_hostname:` is not set). Firstly you'll need to clean the existing config:

```
sudo cloud-init clean
```

And then reinitialise cloud-init's config from the new/modified user-data file:

```
sudo cloud-init init
```

Then reboot. See the [cloud-init docs](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for more details.

Comment: Be carful with running `cloud-init clean` or `cloud-init init` it can rewrite your /etc/netplan/ yaml files.

Comment: It will also update your SSH host key which can be potentially harmful (clients need to accept the new host key before they can reconnect)

Answer (score 11):

For the "lazy guys" like me, a copy-paste solution :)

```
sudo sed -i '/preserve_hostname: false/c\preserve_hostname: true' /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg && sudo hostnamectl set-hostname ReplaceThisWithTheHostnamePreferred
```

First command allows the new hostname to be remembered by the OS.

The second part (after the &&) will only run if the first part has finished successfully and will set the hostname to the desired value.

Regards! L

Answer (score 6):

1- Edit `vi /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` and change

```bsh
preserve_hostname: false
```

To

```bsh
preserve_hostname: true
```

Save and exit.

2- Edit `vi /etc/hostname` and replace your new name in this file or you can do this step with bellow command.

```bsh
hostnamectl set-hostname NEWNAME
```

Enjoy it :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're not happy with leaving an older version somewhere, then simply open the file at `/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net/user-data`, and change your hostname at the line:

```
hostname: cm-lc-nc
```

Then run:

```
cloud-init clean
cloud-init init
```

It will then set `/etc/hostname` to the new value and will remain consistent across reboots. This will remove all traces of the previous hostname and in the event that `preserve_hostname` is either reset or ignored for some reason, you still won't lose your new hostname.

Comment: Your proposal is absolutely right as you have pointed out where the old hostname is explicitly left!  And of course, it is more correct to edit there ( /var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net/user-data ) than to simply disable reading that file by editing '/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg' as suggested in the high voted answer on top.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found that, after removing the cloud packages, you can change your hostname.

```
apt remove cloud-init cloud-initramfs-copymods cloud-initramfs-dyn-netconf
```

Comment: I'm sure this will work but I think I prefer the answer above.  Thanks for responding though

Comment: I suggest to refrain from this solution if you are using ubuntu-server package. Why? Because the above mentioned packages are prerequisites of it. Description of the ubuntu-server package 'Description-en: The Ubuntu Server system
 This package depends on all of the packages in the Ubuntu Server system
 .
 It is also used to help ensure proper upgrades, so it is recommended that
 it not be removed.'

Comment: This fixed it for me. Like an idiot I'd installed clount-init into the root Proxmox cluster. Nothing went wrong until the first reboot, then proxmox was down because hostname kept changing.

Answer (score 1):

For those arriving here on attempting to set the hostname on a read-only OS (such as a Live Ubuntu 20.04 USB drive with persistence) the following worked:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

The last line add a `@reboot` command as follows.  Change `myhostname` to the name you want to use:

```
@reboot sudo hostnamectl set-hostname myhostname
```

Big thanks to [`@hs.chandra` for the crontab trick](https://askubuntu.com/a/290102/412004)