# Start script ts3server_startscript.sh after REBOOT automaticaly

Tags: scripts, 19.04, autostart

Could someone help me with automatic start of the script after reboot?
It is regarding TeamSpeak3. I want to start `ts3server_startscript.sh` again if  some unwanted reboot of the server occurs.

I tried several ways, but nothing is working, the only way how to start is:

```
sudo /home/teamspeak/./ts3server_startscript.sh start
```

I tried editing the crontab with this cron job:

```
@reboot /home/teamspeak/ts3server_startscript.sh
```

That is not working.

I tried editing the service file:

```
nano /lib/systemd/system/ts3server.service
```

The edit placed this text in it:

```
[Unit]
Description=Teamspeak Service
Wants=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/teamspeak
User=teamspeak
ExecStart=/home/teamspeak/ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh
ExecStop=/home/teamspeak/ts3server_startscript.sh stop
ExecReload=/home/teamspeak/ts3server_startscript.sh restart
Restart=always
RestartSec=15

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But nothing works. I have Ubuntu 19.04.

Unfortunately, nothing worked. I read and tried suggested help from local threades, but nothing of it is working :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/290099/how-to-run-a-script-during-boot-as-root

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a script during boot as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290099/how-to-run-a-script-during-boot-as-root)

Comment: nothing of it is working, so thats why I started this thread.CRONTAB si not working as sudo also. service in /lib/systemd as well, not in /etc/...

it seems that it is not possible to make this script run after reboot..