# Run gnome-terminal with sudo on boot

Tags: gnome-terminal, autostart

I need to run the gnome-terminal with some command with sudo rights on the startup. How could I do that?

Comment: Don't you mean you need to run a **command**? Why do you think you need to run the terminal emulator?

Comment: I need to see all the outputs of the scripts for debug. That's why I'm I'm running the commands inside the gnome-terminal

Comment: You can read your logs anytime. AFAIK any software/process can be added to the startup apps but adding a terminal *and* running a command automatically isn't. And if just debugging you can open it yourself and run the command or script, don't you?

Comment: I am already able to add a terminal to the startup apps and run a command automatically.
I've added this command to the startup applications:

gnome-terminal -- sh /path/to/my/script.sh

 I just need to run the terminal with sudo priviliges

Comment: seems I've nailed it
The command for the gnome terminal will look like this:

gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'echo "YOURPASSWORD" | sudo -S sh PATH_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT && sleep 1 && printf "\n"'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a script during boot as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290099/how-to-run-a-script-during-boot-as-root)

Comment: You certainly do not need to do that. Instead, tell us what you really want to achieve. Do not ask about what *you* think is the solution to your problem, ask us about your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Several people asking me why do I need to run the script on the startup with the GUI. The answer is - I want to know what's happening on the machine(Jetson Nano with Ubuntu). I need to know if the script running or not, what it does at a moment.

I've found the solution by myself:

the command to run the gnome-terminal on root with some command as an argument will look like this:

gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'echo "YOURPASSWORD" | sudo -S sh PATH_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT && sleep 1 && printf "\n"'

**To put it on autostart:**

create the file:
nano ~/.config/autostart/gnome-terminal.desktop

input the following :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'echo "YOURPASSWORD" | sudo -S sh PATH_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT && sleep 1 && printf "\n"'
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=anything
Name=anything
Comment[en_US]=anything
Comment=anything
```

Then Ctrl+x to save.
Done.

Comment: Thanks--this helped me get my own autostarting gnome-terminal going. one minor tip: you don't need to pipe your password to sudo if you update /etc/sudoers to include NOPASSWD for the specific command.